# Firestore query .toUpperCase() not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am attempting to create a website that enables users to search through a collection of documents in Firebase Firestore. The process involves saving the user's input as a state(useState) and utilizing a useEffect hook to query the Firebase database.

However, I encountered an issue where the query does not work as expected when using the input.toUpperCase() method. It always returns all the documents in the collection. Strangely, when typing the text directly into a message box without converting it to uppercase, the query works correctly.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetch = async () => {
    const docRef = collection(db, "CenterBatchLvl");
    const m = message.toUpperCase(); // This doesn't work as expected.

    const q = query(docRef, where("batch", ">=", m)); // When I use 'message' instead of 'm', it works fine.

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    const names = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().batch);
    console.log(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
    setPossible(names);
  }
  fetch();
```

Please help me figure out why using input.toUpperCase() doesn't work in this case, while typing the text directly into the message box without the toUpperCase() method produces the desired results.

the Message state is set like below

```
<Input maxW={400} onChange={(e) => { setMessage(e.target.value) }} type="text" />
```

Comment: We can't see your Firestore data nor the value of `message`, so we don't have any idea how this code will execute when run.  Try hard-coding the value of the query filter so we can all be sure what it is, and show us the actual documents that you expect to return.  The, please edit the question to show us what you have.

Comment: If, as your question says, you think that toUpperCase is the only thing that doesn't work here (and Firestore is not the problem), then just log the values of `m` and `message`, show us the values, and explain what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: when i log message and its type i get this
`message: hello type:string`
 and i get this when i log `m` and its type 
`m: HELLO type:string`

Comment: It would be hard to say unless we can see sample data or a minimal reproducible example of your firestore data.

Comment: If you added code and debugging, you should edit the question to make those things perfectly clear.  Do not bury important information in comments!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're trying to find results that start **with** the value of `m`. But your query is:

```
query(docRef, where("batch", ">=", m))
```

This query takes all documents (in the index), orders them on the value of `batch`, finds the first one that starts with the value of `m`, and then returns all results after that. So it returns the results start **at** the value of `m`, not just those starting **with** the value of `m`.

If you just want the results where `batch` starts with the value of `m`, you need to provide an end condition too:

```
query(docRef, where("batch", ">=", m), where("batch", "<=", m+"~")
```

The `~` here is no magic operator, but just a character high in the ASCII range so that all results before that are included.

If your `batch` field contains character beyond the ASCII range, you'll want to use a Unicode end term instead:

```
query(docRef, where("batch", ">=", m), where("batch", "<=", m+"\uf8ff")
```